# How do I get back all the changes in VSCode?

Tags: git

I am learning Git and ran some commands to push code on GitHub.

I then made some changes and added new code ran some commands like pull and now my code is gone from VSCode?

How do i get back all the code in VSCode?

Answer (score 0):

Check in command line a git status, git diff, and `git stash list`, just to check if your work in progress was already added, but removed or stashed.

And check if, in VSCode, a simple CTRL-Z (undo) on a specific file would be enough to restore it to its state before the latest pull.

In general, make sure to commit before pulling. That way, even if something disappear, you can always get back to that commit

Comment: On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        apps/productprofile/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

Comment: git stash list and git diff are empty

Comment: @James OK and those files (to be added) are not your most recent work?

Comment: yeah there is more which i did today

Comment: @James Did you save those files before the pull? Does a CTRL-Z works when you are on a file overwritten?

Comment: i guess no ctrl+z doesnt work

Comment: @James What is your OS, Git version and VSCode version?

Comment: git version 2.33.1, ubuntu linux 18 vscode 1.65.0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242587/discussion-between-vonc-and-james).

Answer (score 0):

To undo the changes made or get back the code you stashed earlier, navigate to your terminal in vs code and run the command line:
`git stash pop`
and after that you can now run:
`git add .`
to add your changes and then commit your changes to your remote branch.